# tinyMCE : avoid "width" attribute to be converted in style="width:..."

Tags: html, css, styles, tinymce

I'm working on a mail editor using TinyMCE.
As mail clients have old HTML rendering, I need to set "width" attribute in table elements, like :

`<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="backgroundTable">`

but tinyMCE keeps transforming that into

`<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 600px;" id="backgroundTable">`

My method : I copy the HTML code, paste it in the "HTML" popup of tinyMCE. I click the "update" button on this popup. TinyMCE shows me my HTML code interprated, all is respected. But when I click on the HTML button to show again the popup HTML code, the width is converted in style attribute.

My tinyMCE config is :

`mode : "textareas",`

`theme : "advanced",`

`plugins : "autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",`

`elements : 'abshosturls',`

`relative_urls : false,`

`inline_styles : true,`

`verify_html : false,`

`element_format : "html",`

`extended_valid_elements : "table[width|cellpadding|cellspacing|height|class|style|id]",`

The other config is useless here I think (theme_advanced options and others...).

I searched in the tinyMCE documentation but I didn't find anything about this replace. TinyMCE seems to clean the code.

I keep searching for THE option but if anyone has the solution...

EDIT : even `inline_styles : false,` doesn't do anything !

Comment: yes, tinymce cleans the code, but i do not know the solution in this case - i suggest you ask in the tinymce forum: http://www.tinymce.com/forum/

Comment: It seems that it's a quite old bug but not fixed... I don't why TinyMCE devs are not working on it / don't care.
http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=4397

Comment: i do not know why, i got a few other festure requests and bugs, but looks like the team has other stuff to do

Comment: I'm done searching for that. I tried a lot of things, even edit the JS scripts inside the plugins. It changed nothing...